# Form not validated

Tags: codeigniter

I want to validate a form that has two fields, username and password. When I insert data CodeIgniter show the error message, though I insert correct data.

The view:

```
<div id="acformulario"> 
    <?php echo validation_errors(); echo form_open('cindice/valida');?>
        <label for="correo" id="dcorreo">Direcci&oacute;n de correo</label>
        <input type="text" name="drcorreo" id="dcc"/><br /><br />
        <label for="contrasenya" id="cont">Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
        <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="cmcont"/><br /><br />
        <!--<label for="enviar"></label>-->
        <input type="submit" name="envia" id="bentrar" value="Entrar"/> 
    </form>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
public function valida() 
 {
    $this->input->post('drcorreo');
    $this->input->post('contrasena');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('correo','Direcci&oacute;n de 
            correo','trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contrasenya','Contrase&ntilde;a',
            'trim|required|md5|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()==true)
     {
        echo ("correct");   
     }
    else {

        echo ("wrong");

     }  
 }
```

When I typed correct or wrong data any message of rules is displayed. For example, both fields are required, but if I click the submit button with empty fields I watch wrong on the screen, and I should watch username is required.

what's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you got your names mixed up codeingiters form validation uses the name of the input type as the parameter and not the label.

if your input name is `drcorreo`

then on your `set_rules` use

`set_rules('drcorreo','Direcci&oacute;n decorreo','trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');`

where the first parameter is the name of the input field

Comment: Yes. I change names as you told but the problem is not fixed.

Comment: Remove the name from the submit butto. (name="envia"). Just: <input type="submit" id="bentrar" value="Entrar"/>

Comment: Yes. I removed it but the problem is not fixed.

Comment: @axmug, update your question with your new code. and will take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('drcorreo','Direcci&oacute;n de 
            correo','trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('contrasena','Contrase&ntilde;a',
            'trim|required|md5|xss_clean');
```

Change Your first parameter Of set_rules Method..It Takes name Of the input.

Comment: I change it, but it doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

The code updated:

view:

```
<div id="acformulario"> 
    <?php echo validation_errors(); echo form_open('cindice/valida');?>
      <label for="correo" id="dcorreo">Direcci&oacute;n de correo</label>
      <input type="text" name="drcorreo" id="dcc"/><br /><br />
      <label for="contrasenya" id="cont">Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
      <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="cmcont"/><br /><br />
      <input type="submit" name="envia" id="bentrar" value="Entrar" />  
    </form>
</div>
```

controller:

```
public function valida() 
{
  $this->input->post('drcorreo');
  $this->input->post('contrasena');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('drcorreo','Direcci&oacute;n de   
      correo','trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('contrasena','Contrase&ntilde;a',
      'trim|required|md5|xss_clean');
      if ($this->form_validation->run()==true)
     {
        echo ("good");  
     }
    else {

        echo ("wrong");

         }  
}
```